# grunt watch executes tasks multiple times

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've the following Grunfile.js File:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/build/style.css': 'css/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            stylesheets: {
                files: ['css/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['newer:sass']
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the plugin that compiles sass
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    // watch for, and run grunt if files change
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // Plugin for Grunt tasks to run with newer files only.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');

    // Grunt Tasks:
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['newer:sass']);

};
```

After running grunt watch and saving my scss File, the console output is the following:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...

>> File "css\style.scss" changed.
Running "newer:sass" (newer) task

Running "newer:sass:dist" (newer) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File css/build/style.css created.

Running "newer-postrun:sass:dist:1:D:\xampp\htdocs\grunt-test\node_modules\grunt-newer\.cache" (newer-postrun) task

Done, without errors.
```

The problem is, the .scss file is compiled every time. Even if there was no change.

I don't understand why grunt is running 3 tasks (newer:sass, newer:sass:dist, sass:dist), instead of only running the task defined under watch (newer:sass).

Hope someone has an idea to fix this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this is the problem, but try specifying that you don't want to run all of `sass`, just `sass:dist`. So try: `grunt.registerTask('default', ['newer:sass:dist']);`